# How to return all non-null data in FaunaDB?

Tags: faunadb

I have this sample code where I would return all refs and fullname from an Index

```
q.Paginate(q.Match(q.Index('users_fullname_and_ref')))
```

But the query will return error when there's an empty object in documents.
I have looked at `isNull` method but I would like to know how to use this method within my code.

Is is like this?

```
q.Filter(q.Paginate(q.Match(q.Index('users_fullname_and_ref'))), q.Lambda("X", q.Not(q.isNull(q.Get(q.Var("X")))))
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

(I cannot comment yet so I'm asking for clarifications with an answer)

What is the error exactly and how is the index defined?
If the index uses "terms:" then Match needs to specify a fullname in the query.
If the indexes uses "values:" then the Lambda needs to have the same number of params as in values. E.g, Lambda(["fullname", "ref"], ...).
Also, I think null values are not indexed, so the 2nd piece of code is redundant, depending on the index definition.